# How to setup babel-plugin-react-css-modules with nextjs (create-next-app) 10?

Tags: reactjs, sass, babeljs, next.js

I've been trying to make the *babel css modules plugin* work with create-next-app (nextjs 10), but found no resources online or in their offical docs. Hope to get help here!

Also a small note, I'm using **SCSS** (not CSS) in my project.

Edit: [this](https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules#installation) is the plugin I'm taking about.

Comment: For babel-plugin-react-css-modules plugin to work these steps needs to be followed,
1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-css-modules#configuration
2. Since you are using scss, follow this step
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-css-modules#configurate-syntax-loaders